# how to use android camera with OpenGL ES to work?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, shader, android-camera

I want to use the OpenGL ES for the Android camera preview and Save the captured Image.

I like to use the OpenGL ES in Android camera to give some effect to the Android camera. So please anyone tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 7):

you need to implement the `android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback` interface and override the method

```
public synchronized void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                        myOpenGLObject.receiveFrames(data);
        }
```

to read the frames received from the camera callback.
I suggest you to have a look into the andar source http://code.google.com/p/andar/. Especially the class [CameraPreviewHandler.java](http://code.google.com/p/andar/source/browse/trunk/AndAR/src/edu/dhbw/andar/CameraPreviewHandler.java).

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Atlease i got one reply. But please see the updated question.

Comment: If i got proper result what i want, i will surly going to accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

A faster way is to avoid the `onPreviewFrame` callback and use `SurfaceTexture` as the texture to which the camera renders the preview.
Have a look at the example inside grafika which more or less does the same : https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/CameraCaptureActivity.java